# How to use a list of objects in a provider with Riverpod

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, riverpod

I am building an Flutter app and am struggling with the whole provider/consumer concept and how to solve my problem using Riverpod. I have not worked with Providers/consumers before so I am having a little trouble wrapping my head around it.

Below I've got an example diagram and requirements I am trying to meet.

Basically, I have a Form object that I would like to be used in a provider, as it is needed in various places in the app. The object has methods that update its state.

The widget from getForm() updates the data, and when data is updated (user hits save), I want the widget shown from getPreview() to update. This also updates the status, so when going back to screen 1, the list item shows "completed" now.

Requirements/Specs:

1. Form data is stored in json on a user device, so provider needs to pull from the SharedPreferences if it exists there, else just default. This would update the "data" value in the Form Object.
2. The list is a known size.
3. The forms are updated (i.e. the "data") from multiple points in the app, I show one example.
4. When a form changes, the list shows the "status" in the list object (say a card) and only that list entry is updated, rather than rebuilding the whole list.
5. Tapping a list entry in screen 1 goes to screen 2. This screen also has access to the Form Object and shows two widgets.

   5.1) an update in getForm() to the data will update the getPreview() widget.

I've looked at this [todo](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/blob/master/examples/todos/lib/main.dart) example but there is a lot there to understand and I get lost.

I am not looking for anyone to build out any code for me, just to explain some concepts I will need and maybe short snippets demonstrating them. Such as how to have a list of Form objects where I can update any item in that list and show that update in a list without rebuilding all the other items.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the simplest case it looks like this (+ some pseudocode):

Data processing `Forms`:

```dart
class Form {
  Form(this.data, this.status, this.lastEditTime);

  final data;
  final status;
  final lastEditTime;
}

final formsProvider = StateNotifierProvider<FormsNotifier, List<Form>>(
  (ref) {
    return FormsNotifier(ref);
  },
);

class FormsNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Form>> {
  FormsNotifier(this._ref) : super([]) {
    _init();
  }

  final Ref _ref;

  _init() async {
    final yourData = await _ref.read(_dbProvider).get();

    state = yourData; // your list data from db
  }

  saveNewData(data) async {
    // perform the necessary operations, save to the database and update the state.
    // ...

    await _ref.read(_dbProvider).set(data);
    state = data;
  }
}
```

data base:

```dart
class SharedPreferences {
  /*
  * emulation of the 'shared_preferences' package 
  */

  // init method
  static getInstance() async {}

  get() async {}

  set(data) async {}
}

final _dbProvider =
    Provider<SharedPreferences>((ref) => throw UnimplementedError());
```

main method

```
Future<void> main() async {
  final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      overrides: [
        _dbProvider.overrideWithValue(sharedPreferences),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Ui widgets:

```dart
class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return const Screen1();
  }
}

class Screen1 extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Screen1({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final List forms = ref.watch(formsProvider);
    return ListView(
      children: [
        CardWidget(cardParameters: form[1], onPressed: () {/*go screen2*/}),
        CardWidget(cardParameters: form[2], onPressed: () {/*go screen2*/}),
        // ...
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Screen2 extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Screen2({
    Key? key,
    this.form,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final form;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final newDataController = DataInputter();

    return Column(
      children: [
        PreviewWidget(form),
        FormWidget(form),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            await ref
                .read(formsProvider.notifier)
                .saveNewData(newDataController.data);

            // then go to screen 1
          },
          child: Text('Save New Data'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to write very simply, too exaggerated in some places. First you have to initialize the database asynchronously. In addition to the above method, you can use the `AsyncNotifierProvider` from Riverpod 2.0. You will probably also need the `freezed` package to make `Form` immutable.

Next, you need to decide where the class will `live' with routes and how the routing in general will be organized.

Here's a helpful article to help you understand riverpod better.

[Flutter Riverpod 2.0: The Ultimate Guide](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-state-management-riverpod/)